# Bash: command substitution to return string, skips if statement

Tags: bash

I'm writing a bash script which will use `curl` to make a POST.
The `make_request` function should run curl, take it's response and compare the exit code.

The **PROBLEM** is: the if statements doesn't run and the script goes to `parse_response`

```bash
#! /bin/bash
AUTH_BEARER=yaddayadda

unknown() {
    echo "UNKNOWN: $1"
    exit 3
}

make_request() {
  local response
  local exit_status

  response=$(curl --max-time 1 --location --request POST 'https://api.cloudflare.com/client/v4/graphql/' \
  --header 'Authorization: Bearer "'$AUTH_BEARER'"' \
  --header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
  --data-raw "$data")

  exit_status=$?

  # Check if curl command was successful
  if [ $exit_status -ne 0 ]; then
    unknown "Curl exited with: $exit_status"
  else
    echo "$response"
  fi
}

data=yaddayadda

# take response and
response=$(make_request)
# parse it
parse_response "$response"
```

**EDIT**: adding `set -x` output (aaaaaaapi is to make it fail)

```bash
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: aaaaaaaapi.cloudflare.com
++ response=
++ exit_status=6
++ '[' 6 -ne 0 ']'
++ unknown 'Curl exited with: 6'
++ echo 'UNKNOWN: Curl exited with: 6'
++ exit 3
+ response='UNKNOWN: Curl exited with: 6'
+ parse_response 'UNKNOWN: Curl exited with: 6'
+ local response
+ response='UNKNOWN: Curl exited with: 6'
+ local errors
++ echo 'UNKNOWN: Curl exited with: 6'
++ jq .errors
parse error: Invalid numeric literal at line 1, column 8
+ errors=
+ '[' '' '!=' null ']'
+ local code
+ local message
++ echo 'UNKNOWN: Curl exited with: 6'
++ jq '.errors[].code'
parse error: Invalid numeric literal at line 1, column 8
+ code=
++ echo 'UNKNOWN: Curl exited with: 6'
++ jq '.errors[].message'
parse error: Invalid numeric literal at line 1, column 8
+ message=
+ unknown 'API error: message= - code='
+ echo 'UNKNOWN: API error: message= - code='
UNKNOWN: API error: message= - code=
+ exit 3
```

**EDIT2**: I believe this is the problem: `response='UNKNOWN: Curl exited with: 6'`.
Basically, when I use `echo` inside `unknown` function, that echoed goes straight into `response` which is in the main script.

Unfortunately I cannot use *nameref* because of bash version

Comment: `set -x` is your friend

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're `exit`ing from a subshell, because the `exit 3` gets called from the command substitution `$(make_request)`. To really exit, you have to call the `exit` from the shell that executes the script.

Also, output the error message to standard error instead of standard output so the command substitution doesn't consume it.

```
unknown() {
    echo "UNKNOWN: $1" >&2
    exit 3
}
...
response=$(make_request) || exit $?
```

Comment: That's not the problem, unfortunately. Check my **EDIT2** in the post

Comment: It is the problem. I fixed the script and it works correctly for me now. Your problem under EDIT2 is addressed by the `>&2` redirection.

Comment: Thank you. Would you have chosen a different approach for the script?
I mean, does my script have a logical sense?

Comment: The short part you showed seems OK. Hard to tell in a larger context.

Comment: Yeah, of course :). I was thinking to myself: is the script too complicated, or am I not understanding enough bash? :D

Answer (score 2):

Just literally test the `curl`.

```
$: if curl; then echo doing; else echo $?; fi
curl: try 'curl --help' or 'curl --manual' for more information
2

$: if curl --help >/dev/null ; then echo doing; else echo $?; fi
doing
```

> I want the curl output, which is the json response

You're overthinking this. `curl`'s output will already go to stdout. You don't need to capture it just to `echo` it out.

Assuming all your arguments in the `...` ellipses, your whole function could be

```
make_request() { curl ... || unknown $?; }
```

On success the function's output is `curl`'s output, the JSON.

Comment: I want the curl output, which is the json response

Comment: It does still need the second error check to exit the script, as [choroba explained](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76237275/8656552).